# Java Web Application and memory

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish

I have written an JSF web application (I really like the technology). I have noticed that when I use the application the memory used by java.exe goes up and up and it will never goes down. I use Java SE 7/8, Glassfish 4.0 and JSF 2.2.5. The application is using connection pool for the MariaDB server. The more data I pull from the server, the more memory java.exe is using.

How can I find what is causing this and how can I fix it? If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Can you run hprof on the vm and see if there are regular GCs?

Comment: Run Jvisualvm which comes with your Jdk.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with that. Usually java **will** use all the memory you allow it to use. If you want to restrict your VM max memory usage use the `-Xmx` flag

Answer (score 0):

First, a tool you can use to check your memory is JVisualvm. It's distributed with JDK, so check for it in your JDK's installation path, in `/bin` directory.

Then, there are some params you can pass to jvm at runtime. This parameters are util for establish memory use of your application. Maybe this link is useful for you:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: which one is to check the web application on the glassfish server? I can only see the glassfish server.